# How to find the typescript version that I'm using through CLI?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I installed typescript 1.7.4 via Visual Studio 2015. In Visual Studio I see that I installed version 1.7.4.

When I run the command **tsc --version**, I get 1.0.3.0, but not 1.7.4.

How can I find which version of Typescript installed through command line interface?

Comment: visual studio might install it's own version of TSC, and not use the one installed by npm. do you want to know the version visual studio uses?

Comment: I did not install the TSC via npm, but through the Visual Studio 2015. Since I have other versions of the Visual Studio are on my box, I want to make sure the VS 2015 is using the 1.7.4 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check you environment path.Make sure  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7` is in it.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when the OP clearly asks for a solution through the CLI?

Answer (score 13):

Run the command `where tsc` you will know where the 1.0.3.0 version is located, then you can remove it by whatever means. If you then install `tsc` using `npm` it will install the latest version (1.7.5 at the time of this writing).

Comment: The 1.0.3 is probably in '$ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0', which I think is installed by Visual Studio 2013.  You can simply remove this folder from your path and install via npm as suggested in this answer.  I'm not sure you can/should remove this SDK if it was installed by an older Visual Studio without uninstalling that version of Visual Studio.